# Replacing List with other list

Tags: coldfusion

I have a piece of code where i am trying to replace some prices list with other prices.

```
FORM.GETSELECTION   -2,-1,30.0000
FORM.GETSELECTIONTEXT   0,850,0
FORM.GET_ITEMS  YES~25.17,YES~250.0,YES~150.0
```

WHAT i am trying is: `-2` will have value from `form.get_items` after `~` sign before the comma because it is in position `1`.

and if the value is `-1`, i will get the value from `form.getselectiontext` which says `850`.

3rd item will have its value from the `getselection` because it does not have either `-1` or `-2`

I tried somewhat using the loop but confused as to what should i actually try

```
<cfset manageprices = form.getselection>
<cfset indx = 0>
<cfloop list="#manageprices#" index="op">
    <cfset indx = indx + 1>
    <cfoutput>#op#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think that the output you are after is `25.17,850,30.0000`. If so then you could do something like this:

```
<cfscript>
FORM.GETSELECTION = "-2,-1,30.0000";
FORM.GETSELECTIONTEXT = "0,850,0";
FORM.GET_ITEMS = "YES~25.17,YES~250.0,YES~150.0";


result = [];
listEach(form.getselection, function(value, index) {
    switch (value) {
        case "-2":
            result.append(listLast(listGetAt(form.get_items, index), "~"));
            break;
        case "-1":
            result.append(listGetAt(form.getselectiontext, index));
            break;
        default:
            result.append(value);
    }
});

writeDump(result);
writeDump(arrayToList(result));
</cfscript>
```

Example: http://trycf.com/gist/d9e4d20f07b76e0b2cbc8d140a097e29/acf11?theme=monokai

I'm not sure which version of ColdFusion you are using - the above code will work on ColdFusion 11 or higher. If you're using an older version, then instead of using `listEach` you can do a simple loop and track the current index yourself, something like:

```
<cfscript>
FORM.GETSELECTION = "-2,-1,30.0000";
FORM.GETSELECTIONTEXT = "0,850,0";
FORM.GET_ITEMS = "YES~25.17,YES~250.0,YES~150.0";


result = [];
index = 0;
for(value in form.getselection) {
    index++;
    switch (value) {
        case "-2":
            arrayAppend(result, listLast(listGetAt(form.get_items, index), "~"));
            break;
        case "-1":
            arrayAppend(result, listGetAt(form.getselectiontext, index));
            break;
        default:
            arrayAppend(result, value);
    }
};

writeDump(result);
writeDump(arrayToList(result));
</cfscript>
```

Example: http://trycf.com/gist/38e8f85539886faf3ec9202688ca9c9f/acf?theme=monokai